# Why is log(n) a space-constructible function?

Tags: time-complexity

According to ["Constructible function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function), Wikipedia:

> In [complexity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory), a time-constructible function is a function *f* from [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers) to natural numbers with the property that *f*(*n*) can be constructed from *n* by a [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) in the time of order *f*(*n*).

But $\log\left(n\right)$ doesn't map onto natural numbers but to real numbers.

Why is $\log\left(n\right)$ nevertheless a space-constructible function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because when we write $\log n$ it's either in a context where it doesn't matter (e.g. Landau bounds) or with the implicit meaning of $\lfloor \log n \rfloor$ or $\lceil \log n \rceil$.

It certainly doesn't make sense to talk about constructible functions with real range, I would assume your source is talking about $\lfloor \log n \rfloor$ or $\lceil \log n \rceil$.

Comment: but sir, the log n  function disobeys the law of f(n) >=n of time constructble functions ,doesn't it?